# copy data from one table to another table and also delete data from main table with one button in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

i have an admin table in my laravel project.i want to add admin's data in another table and delete it when i click on remove button

this my admin controller

```
 public function remove(Request $request,Admin $admin)
{
    Deletedadmin::create([
        'first_name'=>$request['first_name'],
        'last_name'=>$request['last_name'],
        'username'=>$request['username'],
        'email'=>$request['email'],
        'mobile'=>$request['mobile'],
        'age'=>$request['age'],
        'password'=>0,
    ]);
    return redirect()->route('admin.index');

}
```

this my admin index code

```
<div class="text-center mb-1">
                                    <form action="{{route('admin.remove',['admin'=>$admin->id])}}" method="POST">
                                        @csrf
                                        <input class="form-control" type="hidden" placeholder="First Name"
                                               name="first_name" value="{{$admin->first_name}}">
                                        <input class="form-control" type="hidden" placeholder="Last Name"
                                               name="last_name"value="{{$admin->last_name}}">
                                        <input class="form-control" type="hidden" placeholder="Username"
                                               name="username"value="{{$admin->username}}">
                                        <input class="form-control" type="hidden" placeholder="Email"
                                               name="email"value="{{$admin->email}}">
                                        <input class="form-control" type="hidden" placeholder="Mobile"
                                               name="mobile"value="{{$admin->mobile}}">
                                        <input class="form-control" type="hidden" placeholder="Age" name="age"value="{{$admin->age}}">

                                        <input class="btn btn-sm btn-warning" type="submit" value="Remove"name="remove_admin">
                                    </form>
                                </div>
```

i have seted my input type to hidden to not shown in my admin list
and when i click on submit button it copy the inputs data from this table to **removedadmin** table

now i want to know what can i do to first copy the data from admin to deletedadmins table then remove it from admin table

i know how to do these actions seperately but i want to know can create and delete with on button ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure you can delete the record from the admin table
Just write the delete operation before the return line
Like this:

```
public function remove(Request $request, Admin $admin)
{
    Deletedadmin::create([
        'first_name' => $request['first_name'],
        'last_name'  => $request['last_name'],
        'username'   => $request['username'],
        'email'      => $request['email'],
        'mobile'     => $request['mobile'],
        'age'        => $request['age'],
        'password'   => 0,
    ]);
    $admin->delete(); // This will delete the main record
    return redirect()->route('admin.index');

}
```

Comment: my problem solved.